# python, how to update the dictionaries by mutating its format?

Tags: python, dictionary, mutation

so what I want to do is mutate dictionaries
the function has 4 parameters
and the format is `{country_name:[location, population, president]}`

```
def mutate dic(dic_format, country_name, field, new_data):
  dic_format = {country_name:['location', 'population', 'president']}
  if field == 'location':
    dic_format[:] = {country_name:[val, 'population', 'president']}
  elif field == 'population':
    dic_format[:] = {country_name:['location', val, 'president']}
  elif field == 'president':
    dic_format[:] = {country_name:['location', 'population', val]}
```

this is what I am thinking about, I know it does not work. 
what can I do to get the output be like this:

```
>>>dict = {'canada':['North_America', '100M+', 'none']}
>>>mutate_dic(dict, 'canada', 'population', '150M+')
>>>dict
{'canada':['North_America', '150M+', 'none']}
```

Comment: why don't you use a dictionary as a value in your main dictionary? Anyway, if you need the values to be ordered, then use `collections.OrderedDict`. Like: `my_dict = {'canada': {'population':'100M+'}}` and then you can do this: `my_dict['canada']['population'] = '150M+'`

Comment: what do you mean by ' use a dictionary as a value in your main dictionary'?

Comment: @user2924679: There's an example right there in the comment.

Comment: Is this format forced on you by some requirement or other code; something you think you probably have to use because you can't imagine any other way to, e.g., read in a CSV file; or something you just chose for no particular reason and could easily change?

Comment: @abarnert yes, I need to open a file and read it. and use the format as the content given in the file

Comment: @user2924679: Show us the file format and how you read it, and I'm willing to bet we could show you a better way to read it. (In fact, I'd give even odds that a link to [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) is the better way…)

Comment: Well, I used open('file_name', 'r') and readlines() method. In that file, only few lines with some other countries examples similar to  'canada North_America 100M+ none'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better data structure would make this easy. For example, instead of this:

```
{country_name: [location, population, president]}
```

… let's say you had this:

```
{country_name: 
 {'location': location, 'population': population, 'president': president}}
```

Then your function would just be:

```
def mutate_dic(dic, country_name, field, new_data):
    dic[country_name][field] = new_data
```

Although really, in this case, the function is just obfuscating things. Which one is more obvious?

```
dic['canada']['population'] = '150M+'
mutate_dic(dic, 'canada', 'population', '150+')
```

---

If you had, e.g., a `Country` class, you could make this even nicer—when there's a short list of static fields, why not just make them attributes?

```
class Country(object):
    def __init__(self, location, population, president='none'):
        self.location = location
        self.population = population
        self.president = president

dic = {'canada': Country('North America', '150M+')}

dic['canada'].population = '100M+'
```

---

Either way, you could probably read the data file directly into one of these formats. Since you haven't shown us the file, I'll make one up, and show how to read it:

datafile:

```
name,location,population,president
Canada,North America,100M+,none
France,Europe,65.7M,Hollande
```

script:

```
import csv
with open('datafile', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    dic = {row['name'].lower(): row for row in reader}
print dic
```

output:

```
{'canada': {'location': 'North America',
  'name': 'Canada',
  'population': '100M+',
  'president': 'none'},
 'france': {'location': 'Europe',
  'name': 'France',
  'population': '65.7M',
  'president': 'Hollande'}}
```

---

But if worst comes to worst, you can always convert from one format to another after input:

```
dic = {name: {'location': value[0], 'population': value[1], 'president': value[2]}
       for name, value in dic.items()}
```

… or …

```
dic = {name: Country(*value) for name, value in dic.items()}
```

Comment: thank you, now I understand better how dictionary works in python

Answer (score 2):

All you want to do is update the dictionary?

```
dict['canada'][1] = "150M+"
```

Alternatively, use a nested dictionary so that you could write:

```
dict['canada']['population'] = "150M+"
```

Comment: When you encounter a new country, initialize it to a dictionary: `dict['canada'] = {"population" : "...", "economy" : "...", ...}`

Comment: do you need to set 'population':1 before using ['canada'][1]='150M+'? for python already know population is 1 by looking at the order I have?

Comment: Python will know because of the order of your list. You have to make sure that you remember that order, though. That's why a dictionary inside a dictionary is better than a list inside a dictionary in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
def mutate_dic(dic, country_name, field, new_data):
    field_indices = {'location': 0, 'population': 1, 'president': 2}
    dic[country_name][field_indices[field]] = new_data
```

To break it down into a few more steps so it is easier to understand:

```
list_to_change = dic[country_name]
index_of_field = field_indices[field]
list_to_change[index_of_field] = new_data
```

Note that this would be a lot easier if you used dictionaries or named tuples instead of lists as the values in your dictionary.

Comment: @sdasdadas: If this data structure has been forced on him, this is about the nicest code I can imagine writing for it. (Maybe it would be better to construct the `field_indices` as `{name: index for index, name in enumerate(field_names)}` if there were a lot more than three of them. But otherwise, what else would you do differently?) If the data structure can be changed to something more suitable, obviously that's a better option.

Comment: @abarnert That's why I said correct - but, as you rightly point out, it is deserving of a different data structure.